# Open a URL after a search

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a search box that opens a url according to what was searched. I have not been successful so far.

Example:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.">
</form>
```

And the result would open in a new page, with the string that was searched:

https://www.example.com/ + string.html

Comment: please mention which backend you have used. Url based string required to use queary parameters as you want the page whatever end user will write.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. From what I can tell the reason you "have not been successful so far" is because you haven't tried anything. What does this have to do with javascript? I see no javascript.

Comment: Well the Question' tags mention only Javascript and HTML. I assume there is a server side script that would handle the search request and UrlRewriting rules to handle it. Or May be you are just displaying a search form for another website 

If all what I'm saying is already done and your just using a Javscript Trick to do it @johannchopin answer is OK !

Comment: Why downvoting him ! The question is not that clear but he could be just displaying a search form from another website. So he hadn't control over the other server... possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `javascript` you can achieve something like that:

```js
document.getElementById("openLinkBtn").addEventListener("click", openLink);

function openLink() {
  var link = document.getElementById("myLink").value;
  openInNewTab("https://www.example.com/" + link + ".html");
}

function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="myLink" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.">
<button id="openLinkBtn">
  Open the link
</button>
```

Comment: How do I replace the button with just hitting the Enter Key?